# Ajax Request Does not Respond

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following Script;

```
function FetchNews(user_id,api_token){

        $.ajax({

           type:'GET',
           url: 'http://192.168.**.**/mysite/public/index.php/api/v1/news/'+user_id,
           headers: {'X-Auth-Token' : api_token},
           dataType:'json',
           success: function(data)          
            {

                var comment='';

                for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    comment = data[i];
                    $('headlines').append('<li><a href="news_details.html" rel="external"><h2>'+ comment.news_headline +'</h2><p><strong>'+ comment.news_content +'</strong></p><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>'+ comment.created_at +'</strong></p></a></li>');
                }



      },
      error: function(jqXHR, exception) {

             if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

                alert("Not connected. Verify Network.");//show error

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

                alert("Requested page not found. [404]");//show error

            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

                alert("Internal Server Error [500].");//show error

            } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {

                alert("Requested JSON parse failed.");//show error

            } else if (exception === 'timeout') {

               alert("Time out error.");//show error

            } else if (exception === 'abort') {

                alert( "Ajax request aborted.");//show error

            } else {

                alert("Uncaught Error.\n" + jqXHR.responseText);//show error
            }

        }
      });

    }
```

I call this `FetchNews` function as the page loads, It is at the bottom of the page close to the `</body>` tag. The function get called but no responds from server at all, and when I checked LogCat, the requestState(status) get stuck at 1

Comment: Try to `alert(data)` in the `success` block. Even this `$('headlines')` seems incorrect. It should be `$('.headlines')` if `headlines` is a css class or `$('#headlines')` if it is the `id `attribute of some html element

Comment: I did that but it wont even send the request to the server in the first place not to talk of getting response back

Comment: Try to invoke the service from the browser itself and see if there is any response.

Comment: I am actually trying to access a custom API on Laravel via a PhoneGap apps

Comment: Since this is a `GET` call, you can invoke it using a browser also just to check if the service actually returns any data.

Comment: that is true, lemme try that. How can I send the header along?

Comment: Try the Postman REST client in Chrome. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en

Comment: I use Firefox and among the developer tools, I found a way to send the request along with the header and I got an Instantaneous response of `status= 200 ok` but the Apps Ajax request is still not responding

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56156/discussion-between-nikhil-talreja-and-diamond).

Answer (score 0):

Change this...

```
dataType:'json',
```

To this...

```
dataType:'jsonp',
```

dataType: jsonp is for cross-domain requests/different domain than the origin.  dataType:json is for same domain-same origin request.

But also...this seems wrong..

```
$('headlines').append('<li><a href="news_details.html" rel="external"><h2>'+ comment.news_headline +'</h2><p><strong>'+ comment.news_content +'</strong></p><p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>'+ comment.created_at +'</strong></p></a></li>');
```

Should maybe be

```
  $('.headlines')  or $('#headlines')
```

Comment: I have always used `json` which worked but since I am using headers, I am having  a problem. I am actually making the call from a mobile apps to the server.

Comment: Oh, it could be a problem with Laravel then...cuz I recall having a similar problem once with Laravel and headers being sent already when trying to send custom headers and such....I just gave up, cuz it took to long to figure it out.

Comment: I am beginning to think it is Laravel too cause all my Ajax request without headers are processed without any issues.